# Is it possible to deploy a full-stack node- react app to a go-daddy subdomain?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have built a one page full stack node/express and react application and have been asked if it is possible to deploy this as a subdomain of a friends website. Their site is hosted by go-daddy and they have managed to deploy some Kirby (php) builds as subdomains in the past but I cant seem to find anything to explain how to do this with React.

Essentially I want to be able to access my node/react app as seen below without having to deploy separately and link through DNS.

myReactNodeApp.HisGoDaddyDomain.com

Any Guidance is appreciated,

Tim

Comment: yes, but it may probably require dedicated hosting so you may configure your application at the application level as per requirement.

Comment: @Dipakchavda can you please tell me what will be the price for this ?

Comment: https://in.godaddy.com/hosting/dedicated-server

Comment: @SangramBadi Do am I wrong?

Comment: @Dipakchavda its a pretty lightweight app, do you think it a single page app would need this?

Comment: @TimTolley, when you used, shared hosting of GoDaddy they have the limitation of access, even to my best knowledge they did not allow command access to install application necessary packages.

Comment: @TimTolley for your application you should require configure ngnix, nodejs installation and other pretty well stuff that may not allow to access that is only my point of worry.

Comment: @TimTolley Can I know which plan do you choose?